# Redirecting to root directory of web site with php header

Tags: php, redirect

In a php file, I have this constant:

`define('login_location', $_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"].'/app/login.php');`

And when I call it from other file, into subdirectory of root, for example /sub/, if I use:

`require_once '../file_directory_constant_decalarated.php'; // the constant file .
 header('Location: '.login_location);`

This goes to:

`root/sub/root/app/login.php`

And I want to go to:

`root/app/login.php`

The web directory would be like:

```
root

-file_directory_constant_decalarated.php

-/app/login.php

-/sub/file_with_header_location.php
```

Comment: So where is `sub` coming from? I doubt it's from `$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']` but feel free to check, if it's not in there, then something you've not told us would seem to be adding it?

Comment: @JonStirling I've modified the question. I've put a directory example of root.

Comment: Ah right. This is probably because you're using the host, but haven't added the protocol. I.e. http:// https:// bit. At the moment it's treating them as relative paths I expect. Alternatively you can probably just frop the $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] bit, making sure the URI starts with `/`.